# Unable to setup Apache Zookeeper and Kafka on windows machine

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am very new to Apache Zookeeper and Kafka. I've downloaded below on windows machine.

Apache Zookeeper - http://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html

Kafka - https://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html

I am not very clear on what to execute next or where to make necessary changes.

I went to C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin and executed  zkServer.bat file

```
C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin>call "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151"\bin\java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin\..\logs" "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE" "-Dzookeeper.log.file=zookeeper-pc-server-DESKTOP-NQ639DU.log" "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=cmd /c taskkill /pid %%p /t /f" -cp "C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin\..\build\classes;C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin\..\build\lib\*;C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin\..\*;C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin\..\lib\*;C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin\..\conf" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0\bin>endlocal
```

And Kafka from the location: C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\bin\windows

```
C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat
USAGE: kafka-server-start.bat server.properties

C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\bin\windows>
```

I've setup `ZOOKEEPER_HOME=C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0` and PATH to `C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.0/bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTsOoQ6_QB0 and it solved my issue.

**Apache Zookeeper :**

Create `zookeeper_data` (You can choose any name) inside `C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1` where my Kafka distribution has kept.

Then go to `C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\config` and edit `zookeeper.properties` file and use `dataDir=C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\zookeeper_data`

**Step to Start Zookeeper:**

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\config\zookeeper.properties
```

**Apache Kafka:**
Create `kafka-logs` folder under `C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1` and then 
Go to `C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\config` and edit `server.properties` file and use below

[image]

```
# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\kafka-logs

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.num.partitions=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
min.insync.replicas=1
default.replication.factor=1
```

**Step To start Apache Kafka**

```
kafka-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.11-2.3.1\config\server.properties
```

[image]